# Как убрать задний фон кнопки?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Как вы можете видеть белый фон это цвет основной формы.
То что более синие это фотография которая наложена на форму.
Основной вопрос, как бороться?
[image: Кнопка которая у меня получается]

Попробовал добавить:

```
graph.SetClip(Path);
Region = new Region(Path);
```

Проблема решена, НО, частично, если добавить в кнопку фотографию которая имеется в [тестовом проекте](https://yadi.sk/d/2UTTduTa0gwz7g) и уменьшить кнопку до размера `28;28` появляются явные баги.

Цель на этот проект:
Убрать белый фон который является проблемой.

Добавить в кнопку картинку, и при смене размеров `кнопки`, чтобы не менялся размер `изображения`, который был добавлен в кнопку.

Comment: @aepot Обновил суть вопроса.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5335003/3129992

Comment: @XelaNimed [Ссылка на тестовый проект](https://yadi.sk/d/2UTTduTa0gwz7g)

Comment: @СергейМаерович Что я должен подчерпнуть из Вашего проекта? Вы пишите "Сделал наконец-то что я планировал... Как бороться?" Что планировали? Что получилось? Что не получилось? С чем боретесь?

Comment: @XelaNimed В данный момент я обновил суть вопроса. И даже добавил скриншот проблемы. И даже добавил тестовый проект, чтобы облегчить работу тем людям, которые собираются помочь.

Comment: Я посмотрел Ваш проект и не уверен, что смогу что-то Вам подсказать, т.к. это ... очень сложно. Скорее всего для таких задач, как уже советовали выше, вам нужно выбрать WPF или [Blazor в связке с Electron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MjxgbmTAAM). Всё таки WinForms более для "быстро-быстро-на-коленке", для того чтоб ехать, а не "шашечки".  
Вопрос: а по какой причине Вы унаследовались от Control, вместо Button?

Comment: @XelaNimed Потому что так удобнее.